# Listview subItem null

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is how I populate my list view

```
        With ListView1
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Add("Articles", "Articles")
        .Columns.Add("Prix", "Prix")
        .Columns.Add("Quantité", "Quantité")
        .Columns.Add("Total", "Total")
    End With

    'populate "inputs"...
    For Each item As Container In sList
        Dim curEntry As New ListViewItem(New String() {item.sItemName.ToString(), item.sPrice.ToString("C2"), item.iNumber.ToString(), item.sPriceTot.ToString("C2")})
        ListView1.Items.Add(curEntry)
    Next
```

I try to get the subItem of the selectedRow with

```
ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems("Articles").Text
```

But I get a null exception because the subItem is null therefor calling text give me this error, but why is it null it shouldn't be null

I need to know why is null and how I could fix this, thankc

Comment: What is null exactly? Did you test that `ListView1.SelectedItems(0)` is not null? (`ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0` ?)

Comment: No Listview1.SelectedItems(0) is not null also if you do Listview1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text it return a value as Expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on indices; sample code (first row and first column):

```
 Dim val11 As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
```

Or assign a `Name` to the row and use this name to refer it:

```
 Dim curEntry As New ListViewItem(New String() {item.sItemName.ToString(), item.sPrice.ToString("C2"), item.iNumber.ToString(), item.sPriceTot.ToString("C2")})
 curEntry.Name = "Row 1" 
 ListView1.Items.Add(curEntry)

 Dim val11 As String = ListView1.Items("Row 1").SubItems(0).Text
```

UPDATE:

You can also refer `SubItems` (columns) by its `Name` if you add them via its own method (`SubItems.Add`) and assign a `Name` to each of them:

```
 Dim curEntry As New ListViewItem(New String() {item.sItemName.ToString(), item.sPrice.ToString("C2"), item.iNumber.ToString(), item.sPriceTot.ToString("C2")})
 curEntry.SubItems.Add("otherColumn").Name = "5th column"
 curEntry.Name = "Row 1" 
 ListView1.Items.Add(curEntry)

 Dim val15 As String = ListView1.Items("Row 1").SubItems("5th column").Text
```

Comment: @Mokmeuh yeah, sure... two things and just about ListViews LOL. You were using my code... at least I know how to use all the involved parts on it :)

Comment: *references by index are supported, but not by name* Sure? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x4396ba.aspx

Comment: @Chris read my code. I have included a reference by Name. But it refers to the whole object, that is, to the row; not to the column.

Comment: @Chris that's why I'm confused, I saw on msdn, that should work, the code should work but I will go with number it's only if I decide to add another row then everythings change and that piss me off x)

Comment: @Mokmeuh don't be confused. Chris has misunderstood my statement: you can refer by Name (I am doing it in my code) but to the whole ListViewItem, that is, to the row. The columns are just a part of the whole item and thus cannot be referred by name.

Comment: @Mokmeuh bear in mind that you cannot select different columns, just the first one because what you are actually selecting is a row which is the true item. This item is a collection of sub-items (columns) which only can be referred by index.

Comment: It's not clear for me but  I probably need a coffee ;-) I will re-read that tomorrow

Comment: AHhhhhhh I see that make sense after all take again for your time, what would I do without you ahahha :P

Comment: @Chris I look forward to the coffee-boosted Chris :)

Comment: @Mokmeuh No problem (you would just do it by your own :)).

Comment: @Chris apparently you were right: take a look at my update. I knew that it wasn't possible by relying on the population technique on the question, but you can also affect the SubItems directly (much more work, but possible).

Comment: @Mokmeuh actually I realised that it is possible to assign names also to the columns and thus refer them via string (never done that: too much over-work). Don't see the exact point but in any case I was wrong: it is possible to do it.